# How to run a custom ddl script on startup of Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Is it possible to run a custom ddl script on startup after

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

has created the model entities in the database?

Currently I do a lot of changes to the models and want to drop everything after a change and create Test data via:

```
@Bean
InitializingBean createTestEntries() {
    return () -> {

        testObject t1 = new testObject (values...);
        testRepo.save(t1);
}
```

After that I want to create a database view, but I don't find a way to do that with Spring Boot 2 + Hibernate/JPA

Of course I could disable ddl-auto and do everything with a schema.sql and data.sql file - but It's very comfortable that my model changes are populated automatically to the db.

So I would like a hybrid mode. My models are still populated automatically - but I can call custom ddl code afterwards to create views.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could inject Springs JdbcTemplate into your createTestEntries() method and use it to execute custom SQL to create your view:

```
@Bean
InitializingBean createTestEntries(@Autwired JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
return () -> {

    testObject t1 = new testObject (values...);
    testRepo.save(t1);

    jdbc.update("custom SQL here")
}
```

Depending on your needs you could alternatively inject the DataSource or EntityManager (using native queries) and use that.

EDIT: native query example

```
@Bean
InitializingBean createTestEntries(@Autowired EntityManager em) {
   return () -> {
     Query q = em.createNativeQuery("custom sql");
     q.executeUpdate()
   }
}
```

see [JPA API Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-) for more details:

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

If it's not too much work, could you provide a solution using the EntityManager?

Comment: i have added an example using entitymanager and native queries. In general i would not recommend to do too much DDL stuff manually. Checkout Tools like [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) for that.